# Unable to install iOS app through CLI instruments

Tags: ios, instruments, ios-ui-automation

I'm working on a tool for automating the building and running of UIAutomation tests for iOS apps (similar to but slightly different from bwoken). I've got a solution that's working for the simulator where the app is first built with `xcodebuild` and then installed with the `instruments` call (if not already installed).

When moving on to adding support for real devices I've run into a hiccup where the `instruments` command doesn't install the app on the real device and I end up getting a `The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 4.) : Failed to launch process with bundle identifier <some.bundle.identifier>`. If I install it through XCode it runs fine, but that defeats the  "build and run" nature of the tool.

Has anyone else had similar issues? Or am I simply wrong in assuming the instruments tool would work similarly for real devices vs the simulator.

I run them like this:

```
$ xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos8.2 -derivedDataPath /Users/<username>/some_dir/build -archivePath /Users/<username>/some_dir/build configuration Debug -scheme <some-scheme> CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Devolopment: Build Certificate"
$ instruments -v -D /tmp/instruments -t Automation -w <some-device-UUID> /Users/<username>/some_dir/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyFancyApp.app -e UIASCRIPT /Users/<username>/some_dir/integration/javascript/iphone/some_test.js -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/results
```

Comment: Did you have xcode open when running the command?

Comment: I did have both XCode and Instruments.app running, but closing them didn't change anything.

Comment: This should work but there are too many things that could go wrong. Did you delete the app from device before installing?

Comment: FWIW, for the simulator, you should not need to use instruments.  Just use 'xcrun simctl install ...'

Comment: @Sulthan: Yes, I did delete the app before installing.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia: "you should not need to use instruments", how so? I'm explicitly going to run UIAutomation tests.

Comment: Ok, it sounded like you were using instruments to install your app independently of the tests run.  I misread.  Sorry for any confusion.  If you are just trying to install your built app, you can use 'xcrun simctl install ...', but in the case of doing your instruments tests, you're quite right.

Comment: But `xcrun simctl` only works for the simulator, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used app installation code found in the Subliminal framework to install onto a real device. [direct link to the tool, device install](https://github.com/inkling/Subliminal/blob/master/Supporting%20Files/CI/device-install.m)

A second useful feature of the tool is that it is used to uninstall as app as well.

The compilation command line is shown in the comments near the top of the file.